# Geohash my positions

Tags: code-golf

**About geohash**

Geohash is one of many encoding systems for geographic positions. Geohash positions have some advantages. It provides a short code instead of the two usual numbers for latitude and longitude.

[image: Sphinx]

**The challenge**

Given two numbers, the latitude and longitude, compute and return or print the geohash string of length 8. A longer geohash would give more accurate positions, here we use length 8. Latitudes and longitudes are given as floating point numbers (degrees). Latitudes are between -90 and +90 (south to north) and longitudes between -180 and +180 (west to east).

**Algorithm with example**

A geohash code is a base32 encoded bitstring. In this example the conversion goes the other way than the challenge, we convert geohash `ezs42` into latitude and longitude. Geohashes uses a set of 32 digits represented by 5 bits. The 32 digits are `0 – 9` for the first 10 and the lower case letters between `b – z` except `i`, `l` and `o` for the next 22. That is: `0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz`.

The first char in `ezs42` is e which is at the 0-indexed position 13, which has the 5 bits 01101. The chars have these bits:

- `e` → 13 → *01101*
- `z` → 31 → *11111*
- `s` → 24 → *11000*
- `4` → 4 → *00100*
- `2` → 2 → *00010*

When joining the bits we get *0110111111110000010000010*.

Starting from left, the even bits (2nd, 4th, 6th, ...) are for latitude (*101111001001*) and the odd bits (1st, 3rd, 5th, ...) are for longitude (*0111110000000*).

With each bit we go left or right to narrow down the number by halving the range. The first bit of the longitude bits (`0`) are used to decide if the longitude is between -180 – 0 or 0 – 180. Bit `0` means we go left, that is -180 – 0. The next bit of the longitude decides if we chose -180 – -90 or -90 – 0. Since it's `1` here we go right for the next range: -90 – 0. For every bit we go left(0) or right(1) halving the min-max range. When all bits are spent, we return the mid position (average) of the last min and max.

We repeat for latitude, except now we start at choosing between -90 – 0 and 0 – 90 with the first bit.

The latitude for *101111001001* becomes +42.605.

The longitude for *0111110000000* becomes -5.603.

This example is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash#Algorithm_and_example which has a more visual walk-through.

When encoding 0° (equator or zero meridian) you can choose between 01111... and 10000... The http://geohash.co/ site have chosen 01111...

**Test cases**

```
(+48.8583, +2.2945)      → u09tunqu    # Eiffel Tower
(+40.68925, -74.04450)   → dr5r7p62    # Statue of Liberty
(+29.9753, +31.1377)     → stq4s8cf    # The Great Sphinx at Giza
(-22.95191, -43.21044)   → 75cm2txp    # Statue of Christ, Brazil
(+71.17094, +25.78302)   → usdkfsq8    # North Cape
(+90, +180)              → zzzzzzzz    # North Pole
(-90, -180)              → 00000000    # South Pole
(+42.605, -5.603)        → ezs42s00    # Léon, Spain from example above
```

More tests can be created or checked with http://geohash.co/ and Google Maps.

(GPS positions are also often written as degrees, arcminutes and arcseconds. The position of the Eiffel Tower is latitude 48° 51' 29.88" N, longitude 2° 17' 40.20" E. For north (N) and east (E)  positive numbers are used so we get position [48 + 51/60 + 29.88/3600, 2 + 17/60 + 40.20/3600] = [+48.8583, +2.2945]. Geohash codes can be stored and indexed in databases for quick proximity searches. Nearby positions share the same code prefixes, but edge cases needs to be dealt with. A single index search on the geohash code on one or a small set of code prefixes is normally much quicker than using two indexes, i.e. one for latitude and one for longitude.)

Comment: Are latitude and longitude swapped in your explanation? I feel like longitude should be in the -180,180 range and latitude in the -90,90 range.

Comment: Also, if we want to encode latitude 0, would we do `01111...` or `10000...`, or are both acceptable? There doesn't seem to be a way to encode "go straight to the middle".

Comment: You're right about the range swaps, I've edited now. Also, when encoding 0° (equator or zero meridian) you can choose between 01111... and 10000... The http://geohash.co/ site have chosen 01111...

Comment: I just thought I'd mention that Mathematica shockingly *doesn't* have a builtin for this—and that topic has actually been [mentioned in a non-codegolf setting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26724/xkcd-geohashing-in-mathematica)!

Comment: @GregMartin Geohashing, same name, different approach. Guess they play on the name, geocaching with c is an outdoors activity for walking to and locating spots on a map if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: To what extent are floating point errors acceptable?

Comment: @Arnauld – Variations in results due to variations in floating point implementations in languages or hardware can be ignored in this codegolf question.

Comment: May we return a list of characters instead of a string?

Comment: @Jitse – List of chars is ok. In some languages there is no difference, string = array of chars.

Comment: Can we take the input in reversed order (`[longitude, latitude]` instead of `[latitude, longitude]`)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen – That's ok. Can't see how it would help, but prove me wrong! :-)

Comment: @KjetilS. Thanks. -1 byte in both of my 05AB1E programs. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-ap -MList::Util+sum`), 136 bytes

```perl
@a=([-90,90],[-180,180]);map{$y=0;$a[--$|][$,=$F[$|]<($m=.5*sum@{$a[$|]})]=$m,$y+=$y+!$,for 0..4;$\.=(0..9,grep!/[ilo]/,b..z)[$y]}0..7}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY29DoIwFEZfBZI7gLaXijTyYxMmJx2daoeaoCGh0gAOiLy6tcNJTr4zfLYZOu5crUUkacFIwRSRdJcz4lFxZbRdYBasAi0pha@SQAScpLdjBEYg34xvUy8@@2mNlQBDYN4KTwjk0Q8BQ8wquKGIvBXkOTQ2TGTb9Sohd8RPLGFWq2@HdXEuyzHn@T5IMS0y/uvt1Pav0VFtHb2c23Eqy@vUdlv/@gc)

[Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##FY/NbsIwEITvfgojWQKKvaz/cExqiVNP7ZGTySGVoIpEmojQQ0rz6k23h9GMdrS7@vrz7ernoR7FqbmIUylOabks2/FQl/OhTqusIsqIlcxKFyhJ1bps6/4hxoSlqLNS4qfKQibxkik9r0SbwD8NX@3hQTWNpnWVRCvFuEmkhZCX7sYRwNEzSCtKUX7czv1im5trV23lO8D3OouxmqgL02OeXQGFLyw3YKLzzCHsimg8V8EBOueRmQgxeMutBm1DYIE8YHTceAiFRcOUMRC9jporZ8Fo2mMRORExYuT/eMwZ2CGd9WT2t@vvTfc5zKruZ/X22gz3/f54b64bgqOBB9R/)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 250 bytes

```python
lambda b,a:(lambda l:"".join("0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz"[int("".join(map(str,l[i*5:][:5])),2)]for i in range(8)))(sum(zip(f(a,180,-180),f(b,90,-90)),()))
f=lambda a,u,l,p=20:p and([1]+f(a,u,(u+l)/2,p-1)if u+l<a*2else[0]+f(a,(u+l)/2,l,p-1))or[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5NboMwEAXgfU9hsZoJEwoGUoPKSVwWpsHEqTEuP22Ty1PSJpvRPOl70vOX@TS4dO2qt9Wqvjkq1pAq4f7bMgii82AcBHHC0yw/vIiieT@2ujudP3rnP8dpXr6@fy7XQBo3w4P3ysM0j2Sl2eVlLcu8RiSOtR5GZphxbFSua0EgIkxLD1fjQYOiRMS03w6ShoaKLRTx1oTNPenqPkvRQpZ8xePSM@WOIJM6vLUXgiW0@MzJ7xM0mm3pVe14a6dWxv/mIeyfwWGU9erH2/gOwkxEIhcpsZBHvMhyxPUX)

I think using named functions would probably be better... anyway. I don't have time to golf this further yet, so just posting it here first.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>64</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> <s>42</s> 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
90x‚R/>19o*î<Dd*b20jð0:SÅ=5ôJCžhA«„ŠÙaмsè
```

-19 bytes by porting [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212394/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!
-1 byte by taking the input in reversed order.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9vc2FiaWX//zkweOKAmlIvPjE5byrDrjxEZCpiMjBqw7AwOlPDhT01w7RKQ8W@aEHCq@KAnsWgw5lh0Lxzw6j//1stNS42MDMsNDIuNjA1XQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY2xSgNBEIZf5bhKs3vj7OxOdkc0hyRVSi2PKxIU1CZFQEyXRh/ALhZiGQiEFClFwSW9z3Avcu5pNT8f3//PbD6Z3t20D4syz5rnlywvF63gY7N8vTwZGJn14vZsdN2bEt7HHZ5exadzjvvx8PB5e/G9aZZvh/e4mvx8zOO6HZXjPDuKX8e5bqtKEZA41soFCBxsravCO0DnGBNE6AchTlRZA8Z6rxUJiOc/01kgk1xdEIGwEdOZxOCDRdLKp45HcR01IQ0KdrUuFv@RoY82PaJ0ua5/AQ).

**Original <s>64</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 60 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
εd©ˆ¾ƵΔN>÷‚19FÐÆÄ;UÅmyÄ‹®Qˆε¯θ®QNÊiXNi-ë+]¯Å=5ôJCžhA«„ŠÙaмsè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AYIAff9vc2FiaWX//861ZMKpy4bCvsa1zpROPsO34oCaMTlGw5DDhsOEO1XDhW15w4TigLnCrlHLhs61wq/OuMKuUU7DimlYTmktw6srXcKvw4U9NcO0SkPFvmhBwqvigJ7FoMOZYdC8c8Oo//9bLTUuNjAzLDQyLjYwNV3/LS1uby1sYXp5) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY0/S8NAGMa/SsikJHfc314O0SCKQ4eAgyKEDBEFA2qHghCnDG0GJxEXHcRRKbRLgwpS4V7qUgh@hnyReNHpffjxe553MEyPs9P2Kg9dpynvHDfM3bauTszrqjSL76q@j7bgrSkeqd6DWyhhtHEA44scRk3xYab7q7KuzKx@tzGCm@woyhBMvMTMYLwpYd7fWS7Ots2kKZ6Wz/CQ/nwO4aV18eFu2HedNfhad30zb@PYY5hpIX1PBDiQAU/8GCmBiRCSWEhwL9BMWupxiilXyveYxlrJP1NwzKh1fcQY1pJq2plMYhVwwnxP2Y4iWnSUBnZQk67WRfQfJe4Rbh8xe2WStAhdDtB5ep3/Ag).

Both take the input as `[longitude, latitude]` and output as a list of characters.

**Explanation:**

```python
90                # Push 90
  x               # Double it to 180 (without popping)
   ‚              # Pair them together: [90,180]
    R             # Reverse it: [180,90]
     /            # Divide the (implicit) input-pair by these
      >           # Increase both by 1
       19o        # Push 2^19: 524288
          *       # Multiply both decimals by this 524288
           î      # Ceil both to an integer
            <     # Then decrease them by 1
                  # (ceil + decrement cannot be floor, if they already are integers)
             Dd   # Create a copy, and check if it's >=0 (1 if >=0; 0 if <0)
               *  # Multiply this to the pair (-1 becomes 0, else it stays the same)
b                 # Convert both integers to a binary string
 20j              # Pad them with leading spaces up to a length of 20
    ð0:           # Replace all spaces with 0s
       S          # Convert it to a flattened list of digits
Å=                # Shuffle this list ([a,b,c,d,e,f] → [a,d,b,e,c,f])
  5ô              # Split this into parts of size 5
    J             # Join each inner list together to a string
     C            # Convert each binary string to a base-10 integer
žh                # Push builtin "0123456789"
  A«              # Append the lowercase alphabet
    „ŠÙa          # Push dictionary string "oila"
        м         # Remove those characters from the string
         s        # Swap to get the list of integers at the top again
          è       # And (0-based) index them into the string
                  # (after which the list of characters is output implicitly
```

```python
ε                 # Map both values in the pair to:
 d                #  Pop and check if it's non-negative (1 if >=0; 0 if <0)
  ©               #  Store this in variable `®` (without popping)
   ˆ              #  And pop and add it to the global_array
 ¾                #  Push 0
  ƵΔ              #  Push compressed 180
    N             #  Push the 0-based map-index
     >            #  Increase it by 1 to make it 1-based
      ÷           #  Divide the 180 by this (longitude=180; latitude=90)
       ‚          #  Pair it together with the 0
 19F              #  Loop 19 times:
    Ð             #   Triplicate the current pair
     ÆÄ           #   Pop one, and get the absolute difference
       ;          #   Halve this
        U         #   Pop and store this halved difference in variable `X`
     Åm           #   Pop another copy, and take its average
         ‹        #   Check that it's smaller than
       yÄ         #   the absolute value of the current map value
                  #   (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
          ®Q      #   Check if this is equal to `®`
                  #   (this will invert the boolean for negative values)
            ˆ     #   Pop and add this to the global_array
     ε            #   Map over the third pair:
      ¯θ          #    Push the last value of the global_array
        ®Q        #    Check it this is equal to `®`
                  #    (to invert for negative values again)
          NÊi     #    If this is NOT equal to the 0-based inner map-index:
             X    #     Push variable `X`
              Ni  #     If the 0-based inner map-index is 1:
                - #      Subtract `X` from the current value we're mapping over
               ë  #     Else:
                + #      Add it instead
]                 # Close both if-statements, both maps, and the loop
 ¯                # Push the global_array
Å=5ôJCžhA«„ŠÙaмsè # Same as above
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `„ŠÙa` is `"oila"` and `ƵΔ` is `180`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 65 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υ⌈×Ｘ²¦¹⁹⊕∕Ｎ×⁹⁰⊕ιＵＭυ◧⎇‹ι²ω⍘⊖ι !²⁰⭆⪪⭆²⁰⭆⮌υ§λι⁵§⁺⭆χλΦβ¬№ailoλ⍘ι !
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/dTsMwDIXv9xShV67IUBco0rQr6IRUaUwV2wtkrccipUmVnw6evrhUiC43lu3j75zUF@lqK/UwnK1jIFJWRX@ByFmBSivzCUfVoofKXtGB4Gy1TjkrTe2wRROwga3qVYNQmi6GfWxPJCPFdLXObrUqnd5m8S67wratNM3oVclmh@cAR3RGum/YofegOBNEunL2Kj0eghvTbHFO4yxhd0lKVWQjtSJNgElKDnDotJr3gvL8dx/Yo/MIke5fQmka/ALN2RiSs3w2rHT0M8qKKJrWb0oH@u2Js70NUNhI3olU2ibj/pcyS67@wqabYbh/Eg/PWb5Y5lQeh2WvfwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υ⌈×Ｘ²¦¹⁹⊕∕Ｎ×⁹⁰⊕ι
```

Input both numbers. Divide the first by 90 and the second by 180, then increment both, then multiply by 524288, then round up.

```
ＵＭυ◧⎇‹ι²ω⍘⊖ι !²⁰
```

If the result is greater than 2, then decrement and convert to base 2 using a custom digit set, and pad to 20 "digits". (This doesn't work for 0 because it would become negative and it doesn't work for 1 because of a bug in the version of Charcoal on TIO.)

```
⭆⪪⭆²⁰⭆⮌υ§λι⁵§⁺⭆χλΦβ¬№ailoλ⍘ι !
```

Shuffle the bits, split into groups of five, decode each group from base 2 using the same digit set, then look up the digit in a table of digits and letters excluding `ailo`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You are, the edge case in question being the North Pole.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>149</s> <s>147</s> <s>144</s> 128 bytes

*Edit: -16 bytes thanks to Giuseppe, by using more code-efficient matrix operations (`rbind`, `%*%`)*

```r
function(l,m,d=function(x)((x+180)*5825.422)%/%2^(20:1)%%2)c(0:9,letters[-c(1,3:5*3)])[1+2^(4:0)%*%matrix(rbind(d(m),d(l*2)),5)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFPitswFIf3cwrBYJBiRZVlKbYCs@lQZjOUwsxumIJiy7WobTmy3Lo5QA/QW/QcvUkvkto4idNC30Z/0Pfje0/u@EnbUnXl3bHom8wb28AK1zi/uxwHBOEQRilFK5EyQThjKHgTsI@Q0W2EgoChDNKtxJX2XrvuZZ3BCMdbsYrRK3qJwvEl31IUrIJaeWcG6HamyWEOa4RzWK0YQlig17MJDHlKUpHGGISMMMkFAlPdgt/ff4CeSt83@36@eWeKQlfg2X7V7mbhKdmkkgkM1gknlHNB0ZnPnXBJu2ETH3JGNlTcgievfK@BLcCj2Wnnvy1ZTBKZiMkljkgUJwlaXDq/512aFfPNc6nBg9PKg6e2NM0Axt2DOaglKxkTEir51JggSRpTdvHqu/xz0e3TOeu9db4E96rVF3rNGJEiktHYFY8Ji8a@LnQispr5oZ3ppZ370pnOY/DWqYOpFhNJR4fpS8F1zVmHU12bfLDVlclEr/9D01OdTGz/L30a@pggxjVGf9H60HHWnenHXz9tg8dxKtOAwtka6EHVbaWB2tkv@ub4Bw)

Outputs vector of characters.

**How?** (before Giuseppe's golfing)

```r
geohash=
function(l,m,               # l=latitude, m=longitude
d=function(x)               # d=helper function to calculate bits from lat or long
  ((x+180)*5825.422)        #   scale by 5825.422 == 2^20/180
  %/%2^(20:1)%%2            #   convert to binary bits
)
c(0:9,                      # encode using digits 0..9, joined to
letters[-c(1,9,12,15)])     # letters except a,i,l,o
[1+                         # 1-based indexing
  colSums(                  # sums of each column of matrix
                            # columns represent each 5-bit character
    matrix( ... ,5,8)       # format numbers into matrix with 5 rows & 8 columns
      t(                    # using transpose of
        matrix(             # matrix of
          c(d(m),d(l*2)),,2)# longitude bits, latitude bits x2, in rows
      )
    *2^(4:0))]              # times powers of 2 to convert sums to numbers
```

Comment: [128 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZFPitswFIf3cwrBYJBiRZVlKbYCs@lQZjOUwsxumIJiy7WobTmy3Lo5QA/QW/QcvUkvkto4idNC30Z/0Pfje0/u@EnbUnXl3bHom8wb28AK1zi/uxwHBOEQRilFK5EyQThjKHgTsI@Q0W2EgoChDNKtxJX2XrvuZZ3BCMdbsYrRK3qJwvEl31IUrIJaeWcG6HamyWEOa4RzWK0YQlig17MJDHlKUpHGGISMMMkFAlPdgt/ff4CeSt83@36@eWeKQlfg2X7V7mbhKdmkkgkM1gknlHNB0ZnPnXBJu2ETH3JGNlTcgievfK@BLcCj2Wnnvy1ZTBKZiMkljkgUJwlaXDq/512aFfPNc6nBg9PKg6e2NM0Axt2DOaglKxkTEir51JggSRpTdvHqu/xz0e3TOeu9db4E96rVF3rNGJEiktHYFY8Ji8a@LnQispr5oZ3ppZ370pnOY/DWqYOpFhNJR4fpS8F1zVmHU12bfLDVlclEr/9D01OdTGz/L30a@pggxjVGf9H60HHWnenHXz9tg8dxKtOAwtka6EHVbaWB2tkv@ub4Bw)

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe!  That's the second time in as many days that one of my answers has been up-golfed using ```%*%```...  How many more before I actually remember to use it, I wonder...?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 174 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,c='',n=1,x=0,y=0,z=(-45,45):n<7**7and f(a,b,c+'%i%i'%(b>y,a>x),n*2,x+z[a>x]/n,y+z[b>y]/n*2)or c and'0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz'[int(c[:5],2)]+f(*z,c[5:],n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZNRjpswEIbfOcVI1QoIDjXGDhCVfWi13ZdVW2n3LcoDEFPcJYYY0wUO0AP0Fj1Hb9KLpN40WW3T7UjWDPZ8499j0466amS435dpnW3zTQYZylGR2jaSaYCGFKPRjCl15pQhytylfBPNZlEmN1A6h1zPvhAXwr5w8ssRZZeDi@SMoMGbVuZj/Vqi0YRmzYQz4jYKCjC0jQMSUraI4iQvNrz8XH2538p2pzrdf30YxsleCamdYrVka0TctVc6swkVK7ZcI@nuHypRc7hTPV9aAFqNjw5AyDY1o9eO63dtLYw/zBuh6TZrnbJuMo1MxmpJ1n@WWvW4z@EsLgK7q5q@3kDObfRYbRUe0vhQ8FbD1cf3V0o1agm54tn93qOxH7M4BI/4JKEMDvbr23focaJ7uevhub2CK1GWvIa75oEry6PYX8QJYTCPqI8pZfhIbxRTUbsgZ/StznTPoSnhRuRc6dHySOInETMCwsAPwih6EtDpHe3iojwrcVdxuDbaNdy2lZADmOhaTJk1J8RPWJAEMKehTwIj51gpYsWW6KH9r5h3lRKdRvBWZZOoLS8yUiKcUNMV5kdxiMmpKd3mvux28VmlD43SFbzLWm55CQYviPFfGQd2OtqL7Kem5tbcsPMXWXy08xM0/Yn1KPEX2FwEMy58zvKpo6T7h735@aORyDQxE9LCcLbpEx2dVJtn351UGNV9XYPoavMf/AY)

Keeps track of the average values `x` and `y` for latitude and longitude, respectively. The function increases or decreases these values by steps of `45/n` and `90/n`, where `n` is equal to `2**(current cycle)`. The comparisons are stored in the bit-string `c`. This continues for 20 cycles, until `n` exceeds `2**19`, which is approximated by `7**7`. When this value is reached, it converts the `c` to the final result.